# Basic arithmetic in GWT CssResource

Tags: css, gwt, math, cssresource

I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
// style.css
@def borderSize '2px';

.style {
  width: borderSize + 2;
  height: borderSize + 2;
}
```

where the width and height attributes would end up having values of 4px.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometimes I use the following:

```
@eval BORDER_SIZE_PLUS_2 2+2+"px"; /* GWT evaluates this at compile time! */
```

Oddly, this only works, if you don't put any spaces between the `+` operator and the operands. Also, in @eval you can't use constants that were previously defined by @def. You can however use constants that are defined as static fields in one of your Java classes:

```
@eval BORDER_SIZE_PLUS_2 com.example.MyCssConstants.BORDER_SIZE+2+"px";
```

Or you could let the calculation be performed completely by Java:

```
@eval WIDTH com.example.MyCssCalculations.width(); /* static function, 
                                                      no parameters! */
@eval HEIGHT com.example.MyCssCalculations.height();
.style {
    width: WIDTH;
    height: HEIGHT;
}
```

But what I would actually like to do is very similar to your suggestion:

```
@def BORDER_SIZE 2;
.style {
    width: value(BORDER_SIZE + 2, 'px'); /* not possible */
    height: value(BORDER_SIZE + 3, 'px');
}
```

I don't think that's possible in GWT 2.0. Maybe you find a better solution - here's the [Dev Guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource) page on this topic.

Comment: +1 Nice findings - I really wish the GWT team would take some time to improve the CssResource handling - there's so much potential there, like Jason pointed out with the `calc()` function from Mozilla.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately my underlying reason for asking the question was to have the @def variable populated by an image resource, for example replace @def borderSize '2px' with @def borderSize value('icon.getWidth', 'px'); But I'll definitely be using those simple arithmetic ops in the future

Comment: You can do: @eval borderSizePlusTwo icon.getWidth()+2+"px"

Comment: Looks like this functionality was removed in GWT 2.5.  I just upgraded and this no longer works (fails at runtime, not compile-time) :-(

Comment: @Roy: I just tested them again with GWT 2.5.0 - and they still work for me. Which exact statement - including whitespace characters! - stopped working for you? (Did you clean the gwt-unitCache directory, WEB-INF/classes, etc. after upgrading?)

Comment: @RoyPaterson FYI `@eval varName icon.getWidth()+2+"px"` works only if you already use `value('icon.anyMethod', 'px')` in you css file. Otherwise it doesn't. I usually create a dummy rule with such references if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla kind-of-sort-of-not-really supports this with it's CSS `calc()` function.

This example shamelessly stolen (with attribution!) from [Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-calc-in-the-house)

```
/*
* Two divs aligned, split up by a 1em margin
*/
#a {
  width:75%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
#b {
  width: -moz-calc(25% - 1em);
}
```

It's not cross-browser, and it's probably only barely supported by even bleeding-edge versions of Firefox, but there's at least being progress made in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could also calculate in your provider method, if you put a parameter in the function:

```
@eval baseFontSize com.myexample.CssSettingsProvider.getBaseFontSize(0)+"pt";

@eval baseFontSize_plus_1 com.myexample.CssSettingsProvider.getBaseFontSize(1)+"pt";
```

`com.myexample.CssSettingsProvider` would look like this:

```
public static int getBaseFontSize(int sizeToAdd) {
    if (true) {
        return 9 + sizeToAdd;
    }
    return baseFontSize;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I would also love somehting like that, but it's not possible.
Even in CSS 3 their is nothing planned like this.

If you really want to make something like that, one possibility is to use
php and configure your webserver, so that .css files are parsed by php.

So you could do something like

```
<?
  $borderSize = 2;
?>

.style {
  width: <? borderSize+2 ?>px;
  height: <? borderSize+2 ?>px;
}
```

But as this is no 'standard' way, i think its better to not do it.